# Applet singleton spring beans problem

Tags: java, spring, applet, singleton

I have a java application using Spring. Spring beans are singletons. When I deploy the application as an applet, and user opens in different tabs of browser, the application instances share the same spring beans and causes some issues. So, do we have any way to force open each applet in different JVM instance or any suggestion to handle this?

Thanks.

Comment: spring beans are singletons by default, but you can change that by using singleton=false attribute.

Comment: @sinha but that would solve the wrong problem

Answer (score 2):

Spring Beans are singletons in their context, not classic per-vm singletons. So I'd say the problem is that the applets apparently share the same Spring Context (which they shouldn't)

---

Responding to comments:

```
ServiceProvider.getContextInstace().getService(name...).
```

How about letting this ServiceProvider use a [`ThreadLocal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) internally to store its context (there should usually be exactly one thread per applet, right?)

Comment: Yes. In the code, services beans (spring bean) are received from a single context. Something like ServiceProvider.getContextInstace().getService(name...). That should be ok for normal application. How to manage it with applet?

Comment: @Response to ThreadLocal: No, the applet can have different threads.

Comment: @Loc OK, then things get more complicated. I guess then you'll have to keep a Map `<Applet instance, ApplicationContext>`. Beats me what the key on the left side will be. If worst comes to worst, you can use `System.identityhashCode(applet)` as keys.

Comment: @Loc or you may just ditch the whole Service Lookup code, start one spring context per applet and use dependency injection (which is the reason why to use Spring in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

Try to instruct applet to use separate JVM using below property within applet tag :

`<param name="separate_jvm" value="true" />`